# Encoding a password with special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in an into to Programming class and the assignment is in part to shift the letters of a valid password by +1 if it is a letter or number and -1 if it is a !@#$ special character. I have most of it working with my below code but I always get the wrong output for the special characters. If I use to the code of anything high like 128 then I get the wrong symbol.

I am using the code from an encryption program from the other week and slowly changing things but I feel like this is too involved for something simple

If I enter the password UMA@augusta2020 I need to get the output VNB?bvhvtub3131 but I either end up with a space, b, or wrong symbol when I change the code input between 26,64,96,128, etc.

I have updated the code to fix small errors

```
def main():
    print("This program validates and encrypts a password")
    print()
main()

# The Encryption Function
def cipher_encrypt(plain_text):
    encrypted = ""
    for c in plain_text:
        if c.isupper(): #check if it's an uppercase character
            c_index = ord(c) - ord('A')
            # shift the current character by key positions
            c_shifted = (c_index + 1) % 26 + ord('A')
            c_new = chr(c_shifted)
            encrypted += c_new
        elif c.islower(): #check if its a lowecase character
            c_index = ord(c) - ord('a') 
            c_shifted = (c_index + 1) % 26 + ord('a')
            c_new = chr(c_shifted)
            encrypted += c_new
        elif c.isdigit():
            # if it's a number,shift its value 
            c_new = (int(c) + 1) % 10
            encrypted += str(c_new)
        else:
            # if its neither alphabetical nor a number, -1
            c_shifted = (c_index - 1) % 128 + ord('a')
            c_new = chr(c_shifted)
            encrypted += c_new
    return encrypted

plain_text =input("Enter your Password: ")
print()
ciphertext = cipher_encrypt(plain_text)
print()
print("Your Password: ", plain_text)
print()
print("Your password is valid and encrypted it is: ", ciphertext)
print()
```

Comment: Sorry I did change that. Didn't help

Comment: Why the `%96` and `%97`?  There are only 26 letters.

Comment: That's be playing with the code in different ways. Trying to get it to work and then clean up the code.

Comment: I only asked because that might be the source of your problem.  Hard to tell if I don't know why it's there.

Comment: Although now that I take another look at it, it's probably because your `else` case doesn't define `c_index` and adds `'a'` to it for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much cleaner approach:

```
def cipher_encrypt(plain_text):
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    digits = '0123456789'
    puncs = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
    encrypted_text = ''
    for c in plain_text:
        if c.lower() in alpha:
            c_index = alpha.index(c.lower())
            e_index = (c_index + 1)%len(alpha)
            if c == c.lower():
                encrypted_text += alpha[e_index]
            else:
                encrypted_text += alpha[e_index].upper()
        elif c in digits:
            c_index = digits.index(c)
            e_index = (c_index + 1)%len(digits)
            encrypted_text += digits[e_index]
        else:
            c_index = puncs.index(c)
            e_index = (c_index +len(puncs) - 1)%len(puncs)
            encrypted_text += puncs[e_index]
    return encrypted_text
```

In this approach I deal with each caharcter in plain text by:

1. Determining idf the char is part of alpha by making use of the c.lower() function to isolate alpha chars and then find an index modulo the len of alpha.  Then I determine if I need an uppercase char or lower case in the encrypted text.
2. I use the same modulo approach for digits, but don't have to worry about upper and lower, finally
3. I find the index for the punctuations found in the plain_text

Comment: Thank you for this. Makes a lot of sense to clearly define the possible inputs and then go off that. I think I got confused when my professor was talking about ASCII and then I try to use ACSII code numbers and it was returning very different results.

Comment: The problem with attempting to use ASCII values for characters is that the upper and lower case alpha characters are not contiguous.  By just using the lower case values for testing, you avoid that problem.